# Java - kill external process with TimerTask

Tags: java, process, processbuilder, timertask

I implemented a method, where an external program is called with a processBuilder. If the external process takes longer than 5 seconds (for test reasons) I want to stop that task.

The implementation works fine when I use process.exec(). but not with processBuilder.start()

I have read some posts but it does not seem to work, since I can't not figure out what I'm missing.

Method:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/.../test.bat -a -b -c").redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = processBuilder.start();

Timer t = new Timer();
TimerTask killer = new TimeoutProcessKiller(process);
t.schedule(killer, 5 * 1000);

BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

lineReader.lines().forEach(str -> LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, str));

int lExitCode = process.waitFor();
if (lExitCode == 0) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Process finished successful.");
} else {
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Process finished not successful.");
}
killer.cancel();
```

TimeoutProcessKiller

```
public class TimeoutProcessKiller extends TimerTask {
    private Process p;

    public TimeoutProcessKiller(Process p) {
        this.p = p;
    }

    public void run() {
        p.destroy();
    }
}
```

Thank you for any advise.

Comment: "_If the external process takes longer than 5 seconds (for test reasons) I want to stop that task_"...`t.schedule(killer, 5 * 60 * 1000);` - But that's 5 minutes, not 5 seconds?

Comment: Also, in your question you should clarify what exactly you mean by "_but it does not seem to work_".

Comment: Sorry, forgot to remove the *60. It does not work in that it simply continues to run. Previously I changed my code from process.exex() to processBuilder.start() and I thought that my timeout logic wouldn't be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely because your batch script has kicked off sub-processes which are still running after your task has destroyed the parent. Change the `TimeoutProcessKiller.run()` method to print off the `descendants` (child process and all their children) and then kill them as well.

The following will print the PID of each one as it tries to kill them:

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println("destroying "+p);
    p.destroy();
    System.out.println("destroying descendants");
    p.descendants().peek(System.out::println).forEach(ProcessHandle::destroy);
    System.out.println("destroyed  "+p);
}
```

The change you made from `Runtime.exec()` to `ProcessBuilder` is not the cause - as  `Runtime.exec()` is a call to `ProcessBuilder`. The issue with descendants goes away if you don't consume the STDOUT stream (**NOT** a sensible thing to ignore as this can freeze the process), so you most likely added the `BufferedReader lineReader ...` after swapping from `Runtime.exec()`?